# Abstract data structure design: save and retrieve specific key/value pair information

Tags: c++, data-structures

I was asked the question: design a data structure that can save and retrieve specific key/value pair information in C++. The question is pretty vague.

The first thing comes to my mind is Hash table or Linked Hash table. Firstly, I am asking for other possible data structure that can be used here according to the limited information.

Secondly, I want to know what should I include into the data structure. As far as I am concerned, a class, associated constructor, destructor, add, delete, lookup, traversal, sorting. Is there anything else that could be used in this kind of data structure?

Comment: Your question is pretty broad, what is the purpose of the structure, what are you trying to accomplish

Comment: @Simon Hey, thanks for the quick response. I know the question description is pretty vague and broad. This is an interview question. The interviewer wanted to test my ability in designing a data structure and coding fluency.

Comment: Since it's an interview question I'd say that you might want to ask about stuff like: number of insertions, number of lookups, number of collisions, etc. And yes, mention a hash table as quick as possible. map/unordered_map etc.

Comment: If it is an interview question you could maybe specify what your study level is at the moment, are you first year universtity student with a broad computation course or having an advanced software science course. This can really influence the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

To create a map of key/value pairs, you'll probably want to use a hash table or binary search tree.

You could ask for more specification for whoever asked you to design that, but if you implement everything you stated, your data structure will save (add) and retrieve specific key/value pairs(lookup).

Answer (score 0):

you can use multimap , here is the link http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/